# mapping corodinates

Tags: android, dictionary, geolocation

I've built application which receives coordinates from a patients device every time a text is sent from the carers requesting an update. I'm now looking into my options for mapping the coordinates received from the patients as well as the location of the carers device so they can both be seen relative to each other. Aside from having Google maps built in to my application is there any other recommended options.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

OpenStreetMap is an alternative. You can start [here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Android).

Comment: adrianp a lot of options there at first glance should get a better look at them today ty for the help